# Como almacenar datos de un datagridview en un txt en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Quería ver si me podrían apoyar con la siguiente cuestión: estoy trabajando en windows form y hago un proceso que se ejecuta una vez y envía mensajes , cada que se ejecuta estas se visualizan en un datagridview estos mensajes se guardan en un txt de una carpeta de mi disco local, el problema radica en cuando cierro el formulario y lo vuelvo a ejecutar mis mensajes anteriores del txt se borran y empieza de nuevo de 0.Esta es mi consulta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9MXk.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m1nb.png

```
using (var logMensajes = new StreamWriter(dirMensajes + fileName /*, append: true*/))
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gdvRegistros.Rows)
                    {
                        logMensajes.WriteLine($"{row.Cells[0].Value} | {row.Cells[1].Value} | {row.Cells[2].Value}");
                    }
                }
```

Si le agrego el append:true que esta comentado ya no se borran los registros pero se vuelven a repetir desde el 0 cada que ejecuto , inserta nuevamente todos los datos y yo solo busco que inserte la nueva linea.

Asi debe quedar solo se ejecuto 3 veces y se muestran esas 3 lineas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y esta es con el append igual se insertaron 3 lineas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabría como hacer para q no se borren mis datos ya registrados o del append para que no se me repitan.De antemano gracias.

Comment: Bueno.. tu TXT es una tabla de una base de datos. y por lo tanto, lo que hagas, lo vas a tener que tratar como una base de datos. Vas a tener que verificar si la fila esta o no, si la tenes que agregar o no... todo eso, lo vas a tener que hacer.. a menos que uses otro metodo...

Comment: Si quieres que sólo se inserte la nueva línea, por qué haces un `foreach`? Un foreach va a tomar todas las filas y las pondrá en el archivo de texto. La subrutina está haciendo **EXACTAMENTE** lo que programaste. Lo que creo que quieres es *que el método agregue únicamente las filas que NO existan ya en el archivo de texto*, es correcto? De ser así, a menos que exista otra manera, tendrás que leer todo el archivo y comparar las filas (o un ID) para saber si está repetido.

Comment: para validar si existe tendria primero que leer el txt con streamReader no es asi ?

Comment: Lo más fácil que puedes hacer es: cuando agregues una nueva fila, abrir el .txt, agregar el registro nuevo y guardarlo nuevamente. Eso abre un nuevo universo de preguntas. Cómo borro los registros intermedios? Cómo me aseguro que el Id del row no cambie cuando los registros se muevan? entre otras...

Comment: Y pq guardas esto en un txt en lugar de en una tabla con un id de errores o comparando las fechas? Te estas generando un problema a futuro enorme...

Comment: es un requerimiento que me han pedido, no es mi elección si es en bd o txt, por ello de que busco que no se elimine @gdianchi

Comment: @Arriel justo estaba buscando la forma de hacerlo con el streamReader pero me marca error por la secuencia, el foreach sin el append me hace lo que requiero pero solo guarda temporalmente la información del txt y yo requiero que no la borre. Esto cambia cuando ocupo el append lo guarda pero lo repite entiendo que este sirve para iniciar en 0 por eso las repite.